# Simplify SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Wondering if there is a better looking way to get this information?

```
while (t0 < t1 ) do

    tag1Val=(select avg from aggregates where name= tag1 and ts between t0-03:00 and t0 and period=01:00);
    tag2Val=(select avg from aggregates where name=tag2 and ts between t0-03:00 and t0 and period=01:00);
    tagRes = ((1000*tag1Val)/tag2Val);
    if tagRes not like '' then
        insert into module.ddtemp(ts,value) values (t0, tagRes);
    end;
    t0 = t0+03:00;
end;
```

Comment: Actually this code shouldn't even work. If it does (to my surprise) ask such things at http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: haha It´s does beacuse this is what I'm using for the moment.

Comment: Well, there are several syntax errors unless you provided false information. With MySQL this does not work.

Comment: I totally agree with @fancyPants, all your where doesn't use any quotes, which is weird how it works :)

Comment: Not only that, even if he would use quotes, the result would be wrong. There would be no addition or subtraction, it would simply convert it to a string.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Sorry my fault.
 Did tag this wrong. It's MS SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select avg 
from aggregates,
     (select t0 as period
      union all
      select t0+03:00  as period
      union all
      select t0+06:00  as period
...
      union all
      select t1 as period) periods 
where name=tag2 
  and ts between periods.period -03:00  and periods.period
  and period=01:00
```

You can pass all periods in a subquery and extract the result just once.

Will be slow if there are a lot of intervals.

You can extract all

```
select avg 
from aggregates 
where name= tag1 and ts between t0-03:00 and t1 and period=01:00
```

and go through the results extracting data for each interval